# Ajax file upload to CFC works with CF Server but not through Apache

Tags: ajax, apache, coldfusion

I have a ajax file uploader that sends the data to a cfc. In the cfc, the data is assigned to a local variable by the use of GetHttpRequestData().

```
<cfset local.requestData = GetHttpRequestData()>
```

When running this against the Coldfusion (Tomcat) directly, all works fine and the data can be found in local.requestData.content.

However if the request goes through Apache, the content is not available in local.requestData.content (size of 0).

I wrote some non ajax uploaders in PHP and CF, just to test if it's an Apache problem. It's not.

I send the content type declared as application/form-data. Interestingly the header field 'content-length' has the right size set so to me it looks like the data is sent correctly but then not picked up properly by GetHttpRequestData().

Any ideas?

Comment: does `<cffile action="upload">` work under your Apache?  If yes then you should just use that and forget about `GetHttpRequestData()`